# How can I catch a pandas DataError?

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I have since fixed the bug that caused the DataError, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to catch it explicitly:

```
try:
    df["my column"] = df.baddata + df.morebaddata
except DataError:
   print "Caught Error!"
```

Gives: `NameError: name 'DataError' is not defined`

Then I tried `pd.core.frame.DataError` and received an `AttributeError`. I also tried Googling this but could not find a list of pandas error types. What is the correct path for `DataError`?

Comment: What is the exact error message that the `try` case raises? (I think there is only a DataError defined in the groupby functionality, but that does not seem the case here)

Comment: Did you try `pandas.core.groupby.DataError`?

Comment: Yes, you're right -- it was pandas.core.groupby.DataError!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Pandas<=0.22 (previous answer was given for Django), the solution is as proposed by @henrique-marciel but with the Pandas import. So

```
from pandas.core.groupby import DataError
```

and add the exception

```
except DataError:
```

For Pandas>=0.23, as noted by ytu, the API changed and the following import should be used instead:

```
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import DataError
```

Comment: This helped me very much. Thanks. Alternatively, could use: except pd.core.groupby.DataError to avoid having to  import DataError explicitly.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in pandas 0.23.0. `from pandas.core.groupby import DataError` yields `ImportError: cannot import name 'DataError'`, and `AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.groupby' has no attribute 'DataError'` if `pandas.core.groupby.DataError` is called.

Comment: @ytu I works with `from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import DataError` in Pandas 0.23.0. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, you can solve as follows:

```
from django.db import DataError
```

Add the exception

```
except DataError:
```

I managed to solve this way, below is the link of the documentation.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/ref/exceptions/#django.db.DataError)

Answer (score 3):

The safest and shortest way is:

```py
from pandas.core.base import DataError
```

or, for `pandas >= 1.5.0`,

```py
from pandas.errors import DataError
```

(as indicated by [@Craig Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8743712/craig-austin) in the comments)

---

## Why

### `pandas >= 1.5.0`

This error is now part of the official API, so it shouldn't move from `pandas.errors`.

### `pandas < 1.5.0`

In [`pandas.core.base`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py) we can find the actual place where `DataError` is defined:

```py
class DataError(Exception):
    pass
```

`pandas.core.groupby.groupby` simply imports it as follows, which is more likely to break after some update:

```py
from pandas.core.base import (
    DataError,
    PandasObject,
    SelectionMixin,
)
```

Comment: As of `pandas` v1.5.0, this has moved to: `from pandas.errors import DataError`
(per https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.DataError.html)